# update the boolean value in md-select using angular material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, javascript-objects

am struggled in md-select model update when user changes the value need to update the flag as true.Actually i have to iterate the length of the model in md-select and in md-options i show like 1,2...5. if user changes the value in drop down means respective flag set to true other should be in false.kindly help me out this problem. following is my code and kindly tell me where i did the logical mistake:

```
<html lang = "en">
   <head>
      <link rel = "stylesheet"
         href = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
      <style>

      </style>
      <script language = "javascript">
         angular
            .module('testApp', ['ngMaterial'])
            .controller('myCTRL', myCTRL);

         function myCTRL ($scope) {
         $scope.chooseValue =false;

     $scope.selectedValue = 1;

  $scope.testValue = [
    {  isEnabled: false},
    { isEnabled: false },
    { isEnabled: false }
  ];

  $scope.submitvalue = function(){
  console.info($scope.testValue)
  $scope.testValue[$scope.selectedValue].isEnabled = true;
  console.info($scope.finalvalue)
  }


         }                 
      </script>           
   </head>

   <body ng-app = "testApp"> 
      <div id = "inputContainer" class = "inputDemo"
         ng-controller = "myCTRL as ctrl" ng-cloak>
         <form role="form" name="deviceForm">



                    <div>

                        <md-input-container >
                            <label>select flags want to enable</label>
                            <md-select ng-model="selectedValue" >
                                <md-option   ng-repeat="(key,value) in testValue">{{key}}</md-option>
                            </md-select>
                        </md-input-container>

                    </div>
                </form>
                <input type="submit" ng-click="submitvalue()">

      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you set model like this? Is there any reason? What is the purpose of this selectbox?

Comment: can you edit and make your question more understandable? I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you want.

Comment: @MikeTung i wants update the respective Boolean value when user changes the drop down value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a new copy of `testValue` object into `finalValue` variable, then do the boolean assignments in that and use. Please refer the below code.

```
console.info($scope.testValue)
$scope.finalValue = angular.copy($scope.testValue);
$scope.finalValue[$scope.selectedValue].isEnabled = true;
console.info($scope.finalValue)
```

We create a new copy of `testValue` using method `angular.copy()` and assign it to final value. Then we use your logic to assign the respective indexed boolean to `true`.

The problem with your original code, is that you are showing `finalValue`, without it being even defined as a variable and also no data manipulations were done to it!

Please refer the below working snippet, and let me know if you face any issues implementing the below code!

```js
angular
  .module('testApp', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('myCTRL', myCTRL);

function myCTRL($scope) {
  $scope.chooseValue = false;
  $scope.finalValue = {};
  $scope.selectedValue = 1;

  $scope.testValue = [{
      isEnabled: false
    },
    {
      isEnabled: false
    },
    {
      isEnabled: false
    }
  ];

  $scope.submitvalue = function() {
    console.info($scope.testValue)
    $scope.finalValue = angular.copy($scope.testValue);
    $scope.finalValue[$scope.selectedValue].isEnabled = true;
    console.info($scope.finalValue)
  }


}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">
  <div id="inputContainer" class="inputDemo" ng-controller="myCTRL as ctrl" ng-cloak>
    <form role="form" name="deviceForm">
      <div>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>select flags want to enable</label>
          <md-select ng-model="selectedValue">
            <md-option ng-repeat="(key,value) in testValue">{{key}}</md-option>
          </md-select>
        </md-input-container>

      </div>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="submitvalue()">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help.can we do it with out using angular copy.

Comment: @Sathish You can just use the original variable `testValue` so the code will be `console.info($scope.testValue)
    $scope.testValue[$scope.selectedValue].isEnabled = true;
    console.info($scope.testValue)`, but if you want to use a new variable try `var finalValue = Object.assign({}, testValue);`, I would recommend using a new variable...what is the reason for not using `angular.copy`?